# Vector Autoregressive model with series of different integration orders

Tags: r, time-series, python, stationarity, vector-autoregression

I am trying to estimate VAR using 8 series. 7 of them are I(0) and one is I(1). I tried to use a python to model, but when I make the I(1) stationary by differencing, it will loose one time point from that particular series in the dataset. So what should I do? Should I difference the series which are I(0) as well to get the same number of time points or drop the extra points in the seven I(0) time series. I really appreciate it if someone can provide me with the relevant python/R code.

Comment: Hi: Definitely don't difference the I(0) series. Also, check that the I(1) becomes stationary by differencing. It's not always true that differencing works. As far as making them all the same length, I would just take the first observation off of all of the I(0) series. if you have enough observations, that shouldn't matter in your analysis.

Comment: @mlofton, consider posting this as an answer -- because it is one, and AFAIK it is all the OP needs.

Comment: I have only 65 observations for my analysis. In that case I don't want to use many lags in my VAR model. According to AIC criteria, if I specify max lags as 5, I get 4 as the lag length. Is it appropriate to only to specify 5 as max lags. Also would a Bayesian VAR be better? My objective is to find dynamic relationships between the considered 8 variables but not to forecast.

Comment: Hi: 64 or 65 won't make a difference in my experience.

Comment: @Richard Hardy: I posted it as answer so should I delete my comment ? Thanks.

Comment: @mlofton, probably. Also, I would consider dropping the "Hi:" bit. I think the standard format is not to greet, and you would hardly find any other answers that do.

Comment: Have you considered the answer you got? (I see you have neither upvoted nor accepted not commented under it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi: Definitely don't difference the I(0) series. Also, check that the I(1) becomes stationary by differencing. It's not always true that differencing works. As far as making them all the same length, I would just take the first observation off of all of the I(0) series. if you have enough observations, that shouldn't matter in your analysis.